# preg_match_all not working with html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to receive the content of the `<tbody>` tag from [this page](http://pk.zntu.edu.ua/fakultety-ta-napryamy-pidhotovky/derzhavne-zamovlennya-2011-bakalavr).

There are only one table with only one tag `<tbody>`, and i want to get all rows from this table

I try to do this by this way

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://pk.zntu.edu.ua/fakultety-ta-napryamy-pidhotovky/derzhavne-zamovlennya-2011-bakalavr');

preg_match_all("/<tbody>(.+?)<\/tbody>/is", $page, $output_array);

var_dump($output_array);
```

And i receive empty arrays:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

I have tried different variants of patterns like

- "`/<tbody>(.*?)<\/tbody>/is`"
- "`/<tbody>.+?<\/tbody>/is`"
- "`/<tbody>.*?<\/tbody>/is`"
- "`/<tbody>.+<\/tbody>/is`"
- "`/<tbody>.*<\/tbody>/is`"

But no one works

With PCRE and Regex Library all should be okay

I don't know what's the problem, please help

Comment: Include the content with the `tbody` tags in the source you're fetching in the question.

Comment: `/<tbody\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/tbody>/is`

Comment: "trying different variants" is essentially just guesswork. *Don't do that* while programming. It's a horrible approach. Understand what you want to do, break it down it into steps, understand what the syntax means, then figure out how to express in that syntax your intentions, finally, test it.

Comment: im not getting ANY tbody from that url :o what response are you getting? im just getting a <body>

Comment: You should read the best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: As @hanshenrik says - there is no `<tbody` in the html on that url.

Comment: That page doesn't really have a `<tbody>` in its actual source. You've likely been mislead by a DOM inspectors refurbished HTML structure.

Comment: Yes, you are right, DOM inspector refurbished HTML structure and added <tbody>, there are just <table>, <tr> and <td> tags in the table and no more, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern it's very simple, the `regex` above should be fine. but I think the problem is come from `file_get_contents`. I just try to count number of lines in `$page` variable and i get this

```
71220
```

But the real code that I check by clicking into that website and copy source code then count it manually, it's about `1787` lines.

What does this mean?

It maybe means that the code that you store it in `$page` variable is not the same as HTML code that you see when you manually click into that website. In actually when you open one website, many thing can be occurred e.g listener method is working, but in case that you download those source code directly to PHP variable some methods maybe never executed and this can make you get an incomplete HTML code.

Note that the another evidence that support my assumption is I can not even find a keyword `tbody` in your `$page` variable.

Answer (score -1):

`tbody` tag may also contain attributes. So you need to match that attributes also in-order to get the content of `tbody` tag.

```
'/<tbody\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/tbody>/is'
```